# Tortoise SVN 1.5: Two people checked out same files and made changes. Way to merge changes?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Two people were working on the same file at the same time unknowingly. One person committed changes to the Repo, making the second persons file out of date.

Is there a way to merge and keep both set of changes without, making the second person, move his/her file, re-update the folder to get the other persons changes, and then copy the changes he/she made into the updated file and then commit to the repo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have the second user do an "Update" on his code. If they were not working with the same lines of code within the file, the Update will merge the first user's changes into the second user's code. Then the second user can just commit his code normally.

If they were working on the same lines of code, a conflict will occur and must be resolved manually, by the second user. Tortoise provides a GUI for making this manual conflict resolution a bit easier.